# Generate a 3D diagram

Tags: graphics3d, code-request

[image: 3D Graph]

I need to write *Mathematica* code to generate a graph from the equation.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself?

Comment: I've tried ListPlot3D, DiscretePlot3D, ParametricPlot3D, and ContourPlot but i could not find away to graph like the picture.

Comment: If there is no way to graph from the equation, 
How can I graph the points :
(4,0,0), (0,4,0), (0,0,4), and (1,1,1) and have the same picture in the question.

Comment: Look at `CoefficientRules` to get the points from the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a start:

```
With[{vertices = {{4, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}},
 Graphics3D[{
    EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[],
    Polygon[vertices],
    PointSize[0.02], Point[{1, 1, 1}],
    Thick, Dashing[0.05], Line[{#, {1, 1, 1}}] & /@ vertices
  },
  Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],
  ViewPoint -> {3, 0.7, 1.5}
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]